# When updating multiple columns, prevent updating null in case of no row is returned from select

Tags: sql, coalesce, db2-400

I am working on db2 z/os 10.

when I am updating a single column I can write query like this (in order to prevent null in column A.COL1).

---

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET A.COL1 = COALESCE((
            SELECT B.COL1
            FROM TABLE2 B
            WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY
            ), '');
```

---

However in case of updating multiple columns since I can not use COALESCE, I have to use "Exists" clause (like below).

---

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET (
        A.COL1
        ,A.COL2
        ) = (
        SELECT B.COL1
            ,B.COL2
        FROM TABLE2 B
        WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY
        )
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 'X'
        FROM TABLE2 B
        WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY
        );
```

---

Can I re-write second query using only scalar function (without EXISTS) and prevent updating null in COL1 and COL2.

Comment: you don't need the `where` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the following will work (I don't have DB2 on hand to test it):

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
    SET (A.COL1, A.COL2) =
        (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(B.COL1), A.COL1),
                COALESCE(MAX(B.COL2), A.COL2)
         FROM TABLE2 B
         WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY
        );
```

The `MAX()` guarantees that exactly one row is returned -- even when there are no matches.  The rest just chooses which value to use.  Do note that this will keep the current value, even when the matching value is `NULL` (that is, there is a match but the value in the row is `NULL`).

Also, the `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause is typically a *good* idea, because it reduces the number of rows that need to be accessed for the update.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what i was looking for. I know that this query is going to update all the rows of TABLE1 that is why I am not going to write EXISTS in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET  A.COL1 = COALESCE(B.COL1,'')
    ,A.COL2 = COALESCE(B.COL2,'')
FROM table1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.[KEY] = B.[KEY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure :

```
UPDATE TABLE1 A
SET (A.COL1, A.COL2) = 
COALESCE(
    (SELECT 
        B.COL1,'',
        B.COL2,''
    FROM TABLE2 B
    WHERE A.KEY = B.KEY),
    ('','')
);
```